# Special terms related to escape velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, escape-velocity

Is it possible that an object will orbit the earth if thrown with enough velocity straight up from ground?if so,how it happens??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what direction should you throw a 1Kg uniform sphere in order to put it into lower earth orbit?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240904/)

Answer (score 2):

No. The trajectory of an object thrown up in a radial gravitational field is an ellipse. (For low speeds it is approximately a parabola.) Without any means of altering its direction or velocity, the object would follow the same ellipse and hit the surface of the Earth again before making a complete orbit.

In order to orbit the Earth the object must change its speed or direction after launch. ie It must have its own means of propulsion.

In theory, if the object were launched **horizontally** at the correct speed it could orbit at the Earth's surface. The same would be true if the object were launched horizontally from a tall tower or mountain.